# Bash - How transform hd0,msdos3 in /dev/sda3?

Tags: bash

look i had the follow variables :

```
root=hd0,msdos3
rootdisk=$(echo $root | cut -c3-3)
rootpart=$(echo $root | cut -c10-10)
```

Ok if exist better methods for just extract the number for that variable i test :D

Well the thing is i need transform for example hd into sd , 0 in a of rootdisk variable

at the moment i just think in make two list like :

```
disknumber=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 )
diskletter=( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z )
```

and sustitute the value detected on rootdisk variable using the the disknumber list for transfor the number into the values in the diskletter list, but for do this i don't had idea how because i don't understand the examples of sites like :

http://www6.uniovi.es/LDP/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html

https://devhints.io/bash

i think i need use : ${FOO//from/to}

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

i think i need use :  ${var//pattern/string}

But i have no idea how.

in another sites i just find example use multiple variables with one value, but i think for this is more accurate a list

well thanks for any help you can gave me with this.

Comment: `Varibles transfor number into letter` Please spellcheck your post before posting.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show an example before and after value for transformation. That is, *"I have `disk0` and I need `diska`"* (is that what you're asking? ). Please improve your Question above rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have list `diskletter`, you don't need `disknumber` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
root=hd0,msdos3
rootdisk=$(echo $root | cut -c3-3)
rootpart=$(echo $root | cut -c10-10)

diskletter=({a..z})

rootdisk_in_letter=${diskletter[rootdisk]}

echo /dev/sd$rootdisk_in_letter$rootpart

# /dev/sda3 is printed
```